# WHMCS java script not calling or woking

Tags: javascript, whmcs

I have WHMCS script but my main problem is Java script not working, I have tried many solutions but no luck. I'm sure about files path and their work I have tested it in another script, but no luck.

header.tpl

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org  /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>{$companyname} - {$pagetitle}{if $kbarticle.title} - 
{$kbarticle.title}{/if}</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="templates/{$template}/kk.css" media="screen" />
<!-- slider0000000000 -->
<!-- Le styles -->
<link href="templates/{$template}/1st/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="templates/{$template}/1st/css/lush.animations.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="templates/{$template}/1st/css/lush.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="templates/{$template}/1st/flexslider/flexslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="templates/{$template}/1st/assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements --><!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!-- //slider00000000 -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="templates/{$template}/1st/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="templates/{$template}/1st/js/jquery.easing.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="templates/{$template}/1st/js/jquery.lush.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="templates/{$template}/1st/flexslider/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
        <!-- popup -->
<!-- /popup -->
<!-- slideshow -->
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"
src="templates/{$template}/scripts/jquery.cycle.all.2.74.js"></script>

    <!-- slideshow/// -->
<!-- fade -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="templates/{$template}/scripts/55.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="templates/{$template}/scripts/66.js"></script>

 <!-- /fade -->

</head>
<body>
```

Comment: What was the outcome of this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Add `{literal}` before start of your js and `{/literal}` after js finish.

ex:

```
{literal}

$(document).ready(function(){

alert("here");

});

{/literal}
```

Answer (score 1):

WHMCS use smarty templates you'll need to add `{literal}` before start of javascript and `{/literal}` at the end of javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Which version are you using? based on the date of the submission I will say the latest or close to it, but I would have added to much code to the javascript link, I currently have mine setup as under the example as - `<script src="templates/{$template}/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>` which then registers and pulls the right location, so if your link is `<script type="text/javascript"  src="templates/{$template}/1st/flexslider/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>` and the 1st is the name of the template then WHMCS you need to remove that and test it again, you don't need the folder name after linking to it as it register the folder name and will display it properly. Hopefully this helps a little bit better for you.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [WHMCS documentation on bracelet](http://docs.whmcs.com/Template_Syntax#Using_curly_braces_for_literal_statements)

Everything within the {literal} {/literal} tags will not be parsed (such as the template variables). However, you would be able to accomplish adding the template variables by using multiple literal statements.